# How Salesforce makes sure that no single tenant consumes majority of CPU cycles?

Tags: force.com, architecture, cpu

I am new to salesforce and just into theory as of now. I have been hearing a lot about multi-tenancy architecture which makes me think how do salesforce divides the CPU cycles. 
I looked into Salesforce documentation but couldn't get a thorough answer. Could anyone suggest me any links which could clarify this a little.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best place to look at understanding how Salesforce manages its multi-tenancy environment is the [help documentation on Governor Limits](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm) which details all of the different limitations that are in place on the platform to help manage use.

More specifically there is [a great post from Josh Kaplan](http://blogs.developerforce.com/engineering/2013/09/script-limits-begone.html), the Apex Product Manager, where he details the new CPU time governor limit that replaces the old script statements limit and what it means for performance.